# Em múltiplos videos do YouTube, como dar play em um e pausar outro?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

Tenho diversos videos do YouTube em uma página, gostaria que quando eu desse *play* em um, se outro vídeo estivesse rolando, desse um pausa nele. É possível? Sem recarregar a página...

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso você precisa ter acesso aos eventos do player do YouTube.

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    var ytplayer  = document.getElementById("MyYouTubePlayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    switch (newState) {
        case 0:
            // Encerrado
            break;

        case -1:
            // Não iniciado
            break;

        case 1:
            // Em reprodução
            break;

        case 2:
            // Pausado
            break;

        case 3:
            // Armazenando em buffer
            break;

        case 5:
            // Vídeo iniciado
            break;
    }
}
```

[Da uma olhada na API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=pt-br#Events)